# Anchor element appears in new line in IE

Tags: css

If I have HTML mark up like this,

```
<p> Some text here <a href="#">foo</a></p>
```

It shows up like I expect it on FF and Chrome, like this

`Some text here foo`

But in IE 8, it is showing up as

```
Some text here  
foo
```

I have a stylesheet I include if the browser is IE, and I can put some special CSS there if needed to fix this issue in IE, but I can't figure out what style I need to apply to prevent this from happening. I tried `display:inline;float:left` but it did nothing.

Worst case scenario, I'm willing to use Javascript / Jquery as well.

**EDIT**
In a nutshell, a hyperlink within `<p>` will appear in a line of its own.

Adding images.

**In chrome:**
[image]

**In IE**
[image]

Comment: Post an example. I have no idea what you're describing.

Comment: @j08691: My bad, didn't realize I had messed up the code formatting. Please have a look again

Comment: This doesn't just magically happen in IE (which version?). There must be something you haven't told us. Can you *show* us the problem? A link to your page, or http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/

Comment: @thirtydot: posted screenshots

Comment: By "show", I really meant "produce a test case". Unfortunately, screenshots don't really help us to debug your problem.

Comment: I tried recreating the scenario in a JSFiddle, but I don't face the problem there. I suppose it is some other rule in my CSS that's causing this.

Comment: Use http://jsbin.com/, empty the HTML pane. Open your page in a web browser, and view source. Copy the entire source, and paste it into JS Bin. Replace every instance of externally loaded CSS with `<style> /* contents of file here */ </style>`. If there's any relevant JavaScript, do the same for that. And, which version of IE are you testing in?

Comment: If you can't recreate the problem in js fiddle you may not have a DOCTYPE defined. Also, if you tell something to float it automatically gets displayed as a block level element. Since the styles cascade and the float comes after the inline declaration, it becomes display:block.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I'm using IE 8. If I view the page in 'Compatibility Mode' I don't have that issue

Comment: I have the doctype set as `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`. Since the problem doesn't show up in compatibility mode, for now I'm adding this to the head:   `<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=7; IE=8” />`

Comment: What styles do you have for your links when they're inside a p?

Comment: I haven't explicitly declared any styles for it. I even 'inpsected the element' in Chrome to see what styles are being applied to it, and there's nothing apart from color and font-weight.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't anything specific to IE? Since you're not having the problem elsewhere it might make sense. You can also try a CSS reset.

Comment: If you want to fix this, make a test case and show it to us. I've told you exactly how to do it..

Comment: I think he just realized the game's on.

Comment: It would be so much more helpful if you could post the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p { white-space: nowrap; }
```